# Can Rails's built-in initializers be disabled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I had good reason to disable of one of Rails's [built-in initializers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initializers), such as `add_builtin_route`, and given the caveat of potential unexpected behavior, does Rails provide a configuration mechanism to disable or remove the initializer?